# Assign value to a variable with a conditional directive

Tags: c#

I want assign the name of a JSON file to the variable:

```
string environment =
#if DEBUG
    "appsettings.Development.json";
#else
    "appsettings.json";
```

The error is: } expected

Comment: Do you need #endif ?

Comment: Do you have a `#endif`? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if for more info

Comment: If you DO have an #endif then please include a little more code as the fragment is fine provided there's an #endif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error shows up if you're missing and `#endif` (missing in your question):

```
string environment =
#if DEBUG
    "appsettings.Development.json";
#else
    "appsettings.json";
#endif
```